# Finding prime numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I need to write a function, `is_prime()`, which takes in an integer n > 1 and returns `TRUE` if the number is a prime number and `False` otherwise. But when I input 2, it always returns `False`. Is there anyway to correct this?

```
def is_prime(x):
    if(x > 1):
        for i in range(2,x+1):
            if( x % i == 0):
                return False
            else:
                return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: You have written wrong code. Check it for 15.Your code will show it is prime

Comment: it will return True for all odd numbers

Comment: Hi!Is there any ways to change it?Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:
First issue is that range includes the number itself, which means that it will always return true (for numbers > 1) because prime numbers can divide themselves...

Fix: change `range(2,x+1)` to: `range(2, x)`

Second issue, the first `else` should be aligned with the `for` (we return true only after trying all the numbers and making sure that none of them divides `x`)

Fixed code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x > 1:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x % i == 0:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Hello! if i change the range to what u mentioned.When i type is_prime(2) in shell.It will not display anything.

Comment: @Marcus `range(2, x)` includes 2 and excludes `x`. So `is_prime(2)` will return true - as it should.

Comment: can i ask u one more qn? Lets say x = 2. x % i will be == 0?

Comment: read my previous comment again, `range` excludes `x` ;) it might be a good idea to play with it and see for yourself, e.g. try to run the following code: `for i in range(2, 2):
    print i`

Comment: yes i got it.lets say x=9,( 9 % i) will be 9%2 9%3 9%4 ....9%8. But when 9%2 it will return True and 9%3 it will return False and so on .So in the end how does the program know whether to return True or False?

Comment: @Marcus it returns only one, with the first `True` / `False` that was encountered - it doesn't keep looping!

Comment: i got it finally. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this, you can also use [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) module

```
import sympy

sympy.isprime(5)
```

Result :

`True`

Answer (score 0):

Although @alfasin's solution is correct (+1), I find the use of `else` makes it slightly more challenging to understand.

The `else` on the `for` loop in particular required me to reread the Python documentation as most sources say that the `else` means ***no break*** but it really means ***completed normally***, which is true in the case of a loop that didn't run at all!

Here's my rework removing the `else` statements which aren't strictly needed:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x > 1:
        for i in range(2, x):
            if x % i == 0:
                return False

        return True

    return False
```

As others will point out, this is probably as inefficient a prime test as you can write.  But it works.